# Doublesided face flickering - z index fighting

Tags: three.js

i would like to make mesh with strong wireframe lines. When i draw faces with double material, one for shading, second for lines (wireframe) i get this flickering of lines. http://jsfiddle.net/jn_09/atTXN/3/ I guess it's directly connected to z-index. So is there any solution for that kind of behavior? WebGL seams to work the same way.

This case is only Google Chrome.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This problem was raised many times on GitHub concerning CanvasRenderer. It appears that when you use CanvasRenderer, your faces get displaced at different camera angles. For example, when you are using some image as your texture – you will get your image distorted as you rotate your object.

See what happens when you set your shaded faces to full-transparent: http://jsfiddle.net/EEywu/. They don’t "jump" over your wireframe anymore (because they’re invisible).

Now, that is where the WebGL comes in the game, cause opposite of what you’re saying, it does not produce the same effect, at least by default. Bad part – you won’t see any thickness of your wireframe lines on WebGL if you are using Windows: http://jsfiddle.net/XQz3g/.

So, I guess your options are: Use WebGL to fight this thing OR use different geometries (line Planes) with raised amount of segment, like so:

```
var plane = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 300, 300, 4, 4 );
```

This will create your plane not only with 2 facets (triangles), but with 32 of them (4x4x2). This way the amount of facet offset at camera angles will be minimal and you won’t notice any flickering. This will kill your FPS if you’ll have many of such planes rendered by canvas.

So let know if that helps!